# Mocking method inside a static class using powermock

Tags: java, powermock

I have a static method inside a class as follows:

```
public class config {
    public static boolean isProcess() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to mock the method `isProcess` as follows:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest (config.class)

public class testConfig {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PowerMock.mockStatic(config.class);
        expect(config.isProcess()).andReturn(true); 
        PowerMock.replay(config.class);
        PowerMock.verify(config.class);
    }
}
```

When I run the `testConfig` class, I get the following exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last
>   call on a mock available  at
>   org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:466)    at
>   org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:444)   at
>   testConfig.main(testConfig.java:18)

Can some one help with this please?

Comment: Can you please comment, where your Line 18 is in the code.

Comment: You have to call the method before calling `PowerMock.verify(config.class);`

Comment: the expect code is in line no 18

Comment: I added the line boolean b = config.isProcess(); before the verify statement. However, I think the code fails at expect statement itself

Comment: [`@RunWith`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-runners#runwith-annotation) is a [JUnit](http://junit.org/) annotation. Why are you trying to run your test code as a plain Java application? On a side note, it may be a good idea to take a look at the [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) when you have the time.

Comment: @SaranyaSrinivasan What are you trying to test? Are you testing the config class? Then you do not want to be mocking it (or preparing with `@PrepareForTest()`